# catch when user scrolls to near the end of the full width of a scrollable div

Tags: jquery

I need to notify when a user gets near the end of a horizontal scrollable div.

I know notification on the end of a page scrollbar can be achieved like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).height()+500) {
     alert('near end');             
  }
});
```

However on a scrollable horizontal div like this: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DBY4D/1/) how can I get the notification once the user gets to near the end of the scrollable area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.images').scroll(function () {
    if (this.scrollWidth - $(this).scrollLeft() <= $(this).width() + 500) {
        alert('near end');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DBY4D/2/)

Comment: Weird because I tried that and it didn't work, yet your demo clearly works... thanks :)